# What are the build errors that are in this program?

Tags: objective-c

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

// --------@interface section -----

```
@interface Fraction : NSObject

{
    int numerator ;
    int denominator;
}


-(void) print;
-(void) setNumerator : (int) n;
-(void) setDenominator : (int) d;

@end
```

// ----- @implementation section -----

```
@implementation Fraction

-(void) print
{
    NSLog (@"%i/%i", numerator, denominator);
}


-(void) setNumerator : (int) n
{
    numerator = n;
}

-(void) setDenominator: (int) d

{
    denominator = d;
}

@end
```

// ---- program section ----

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    @autoreleasepool {
```

// Create an instance of a Fraction

```
        myFraction = [Fraction alloc];
        myFraction = [Fraction init];
```

// set Fraction to 1/3

```
        [myFraction setNumerator :1];
        [myFractioin setDenominator :3];
```

// Display fraction using the print method

```
        NSLog(@"The value of My Fraction is :");

        [myFraction print];
        [myFraction release];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am using Xcode 8 but the books is old ex. It uses NSAutorelease, while in xcode 8 only autoreleasepool is used so I am having problems.

Comment: Wow.  This is some very very ancient code.  Wherever you got it, you should toss it and start over with some modern code.

Comment: The Apple guides, the Stanford courses, and/or Ray Wenderich's site are all good starts.  Big Nerd Ranch does great classes, too.   Given that you appear to be starting from scratch, you might want to go the Swift route.  Swift Playgrounds are out on the iPad.

Comment: @bbum I will go swift eventually but I want to have a deep understanding of objective C to strength my coding skills

Comment: Admirable goal and I certainly encourage it!

I still suggest you start with something a bit more modern.  The Stanford curriculum also has an ObjC variant.

Comment: @bbum Ok I will check it out. Incidentally I am try to build a **higher or lower game** as my first attempt at iOS development however I think I am making some errors. In the _view controller.h_ of the app I am suppose to enter the `IBActionbuttonPressed` to connect it to button to execute the instruction, however in Xcode 8 the format is `-(IBAction)selector:(id)sender)`. I think this is causing my game not to function properly. This is a link to the exercise, your assistance is appreciated : [https://www.raywenderlich.com/25561/learn-to-code-ios-apps-3-your-first-app].

Answer (score 0):

You must declare your local variables, you cannot simply introduce them by name. So:

```
myFraction = [Fraction alloc];
```

is wrong and should at least be:

```
Fraction *myFraction;           // declare variable
myFraction = [Fraction alloc];  // allocate
```

which can simply be written:

```
Fraction *myFraction = [Fraction alloc];
```

Then on the next line you make another simple error:

```
myFraction = [Fraction init];
```

you are meant to be initialising the object you allocated, not the class, so this should at least be:

```
myFraction = [myFraction init];
```

However it is very unusual to allocate and initialise in seperate lines, so:

```
Fraction *myFraction = [Fraction alloc];
myFraction = [myFraction init];
```

is written as the single line:

```
Fraction *myFraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];
```

or even:

```
Fraction *myFraction = [Fraction new];
```

as `new` is a standard method which does `alloc` followed by `init`.

Finally remove the call to `release`, it is illegal in the modern Objective-C using ARC.

Apart from that fix the typing errors and your code should work.

Once you've done that find a more up-to-date book to learn programming from, the one you have is too old.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your response. Which book do you suggest I get?

Comment: The Stanford online courses are often recommended, but just Google there are multiple online courses from universities available for free. As an *opinion* I would suggest you go for university courses or textbooks over general market or industry (including Apple) courses or books.